# How to create table/matrix using user input?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to create a 4 times 4 matrix/table by prompting the user for a value between 1 and 16, and filling the matrix with these values. I used:

```
ROWS = 4
COLUMNS = 4

square_matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

number = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 16: "))
for i in range(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        square_matrix[i][j] = number
```

But this fills everything with the same value. I want the program fill the matrix gradually after each prompt, until the 16th number has been entered. How could I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just move the input *inside the loop?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move the input in the for-loop. Like this:

```
ROWS = 4
COLUMNS = 4

square_matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]


for i in range(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        number = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 16: "))
        square_matrix[i][j] = number
```